# Android connect to Bluetooth via Hands Free Protocol

Tags: android, bluetooth

I would like to create an application which can connect to a Bluetooth Headset via the Hands Free Protocol (HFP). I followed the Android example and have now a `BluetoothSocket` with its `Input and OutputStream`. Below you see my read and write methods (read method is executed by another `Thread`)

```
public void read() {
    while (true) {
        Log.d("ME", "Waiting for data");
        try { // read until Exception is thrown
            numBytes = inStream.read(dataBuffer);

            String str = new String(dataBuffer,0,numBytes);
            msgHandler.obtainMessage(numBytes, str).sendToTarget();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ME", "Input stream was disconnected", e);
            break; // BluetoothDevice was disconnected => Exit
        }
   }
}

public void write(byte[] bytes) {
    try {
        outStream.write(bytes);
        outStream.flush();
        Log.e("ME", "Wrote: " + new String(bytes));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("ME", "Error occurred when sending data", e);
    }
}
```

When the connection is opened the Bluetooth headset sends `AT+BRSF=191` over the `InputStream`. I tried to response with `+BRSF:20\r` but here is my problem. After that the device does not send any other data over the `InputStream`. It does not come to an `Exception` - it's more like the device does not know how to responde to my message. Do I send the wrong data? I have all the information from [here](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=238193): (HF = Hands-Free Unit AG = Audio Gateway)

[image]

Do you have any ideas what I did wrong? Have I missed something?

**EDIT**: These are my write calls:

```
write("+BRSF: 191\r");
write("OK\r");
```

Comment: This might be a stupid comment, but have you tried different line termination?

Comment: I tried with `\r`, `\n` and `\r\n`. Should I try any other?

Comment: nah. But whats that `OK` message there below the `+BRSF=`? Aren't you supposed to send that too?

Comment: I tried to send this too but this does not help either. I have send them with two calls of write. Should I try to concatenate them in one?

Comment: According to [this document](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=41181), the `format of the OK code from the AG to the HF shall be: <cr><lf>OK<cr><lf>`. Have you tried that? `<cr>` is `Carriage Return`, and `<lf>` is `Line Feed`, obviously

Comment: So together the string to send would be `+BRSF:20\r\r\nOK\r\n`

Comment: Wow this was the problem! Thank you for this. It works great now I get the `AT+CIND=?` from the HF. Could you write this as an answer so I can give you the bounty?

Comment: Sure, gonna do that later. Thanks

Comment: If that completely solved your issue, make sure to accept that answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing the `OK` response. According to [this document](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=41181), the `OK`-code consists of a windows-style newline (`CR LF`), the literal `OK` and then another newline.

Do note that other commands are terminated by a carriage return only. For more information on the hands-free protocol, you can refer to [that very document you linked in your post](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=41181).

Example code:

```
public static final String OK = statusCode("OK")
public static final String ERROR = statusCode("ERROR")

public static String statusCode(String code) {
    return "\r\n" + code + "\r\n";
}

public static String command(String cmd) {
    return cmd + "\r";
}
```

Now you can use `OK` and `ERROR` in your code as constants, and you can use the `statusCode` method for other status codes.